# When should a service that runs a localhost-binding program be started?

Tags: systemd, services, webserver

I have a service that runs a program that binds to a localhost port. Right now I'm setting it up this way:

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But the program doesn't actually need an internet connection to function. Is `network-online.target` actually necessary here? I'm using `NetworkManager` to manage my network.

Answer (score 1):

> But the program doesn't actually need an internet connection to function

The you can replace network-online.target with [network.target](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/)